# Thread.sleep's interrupt handling calling Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I'm developing some program that has to read log files and I thought that I built a smart mechanism in it, turns out the code does not even compile...

I made a big design flaw: How to fix it?

```
public class Reader implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean isReading;

    private final File file;

    public Reader(final File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("bf4logreader.Reader.run: File has not been found. file = " + file);
        }
        while (isReading) {
            String line = null;
            try {
                line = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("bf4logreader.Reader.run: Something went wrong when reading file. file = " + file);
            }
            if (line == null) {
                //No new lines
                long startSleepTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    if (isReading) {
                        //Not supposed to be interrupted
                        Thread.sleep(System.currentTimeMillis() - startSleepTime);
                    }
                    else {
                        try {
                            //Needs to shutdown
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex1) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                //Process new lines
                System.out.println("Line: " + line);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        isReading = false;
    }
}
```

I thought to be smart and let the thread to be sleeping for the time it still had to sleep if it was interrupted unappropiately. However I can of course not do this in this faction, as it would require the `Thread.sleep`'s `InterrruptedException` to be handled again.

I think it needs a transformation to some `while` loop, but exactly how would I do this?

**EDIT: Sorry that I forgot to put the idea behind this program. But I want to live monitor a log file, so it would never stop reading the file, except when I indicate such with a shutdown message.**

Comment: try throwing out the entire `if (line == null)` part. `reader.readLine()` should block until there is something to read.

Comment: @zapl not once the end of file is reached.

Comment: I would assume that once a thread is interrupted it should stop doing what it is doing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I believe I have read somewhere that interrupts can occur unexpectedly (for example by the OS), and that those should be "ignored". Ie in my program I want to call `Reader.shutdown();` and then `ReaderThread.interrupt();` in pseudo code.

Comment: What is the deeper sense of your Thread.sleep while reading? Shouldn't you read the entire file and then wait until the log file has been changed?

Comment: @isnot2bad I want to read any addition to the file aswell. As in a live monitoring system for the logfile.

Comment: Oh true, waiting for new lines to appear in a file is a different story.

Comment: OS interrupts happen all the time.  In fact one interrupt occurs 100 times per second (The timer interrupt)  Fortunately these interrupts are completely unrelated and the OS doesn't set the interrupted flag on a thread.

Comment: I believe you have confused unexpected interrupts with *spurious wakeups*, which are not related to `Thread.sleep` but `Object#wait` (a very different mechanism).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks, that is indeed what I mixed up. So every interrupt to a Thread does indicate that it needs to stop asap then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code instead:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
  String line;
  while (running) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000); // end of file has been reached, wait a second for more data
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  // ...
} catch (IOException ex) {
  // ...
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
}
```

The `try (ressource) catch` idiom will ensure that the reader is closed properly under all circumstances, so you don't have to worry about that.

The `readLine()` function will automatically block (put the current execution on hold) until data is available, so there is no need for any sleeps or similar. If it returns null, the end of the file is reached, so you can quit.

If there is any InterruptedException thrown, the thread will properly terminate. This exception is always thrown as a signal to the thread to quit working as soon as possible, so you should never ignore it.

Handling a common exception like an IOException by throwing an entirely different exception is usually wrong, because it hides the actual cause of the error. Instead just handle the error thrown at you in the first place.
In addition an IllegalStateException is a RuntimeException that is usually not caught anywhere, causing your entire code to terminate right away. You probably don't want that.

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to put it in my post. But the idea is that it will live monitor a log file, so I do not want to quit when EOF is reached.

Comment: I added a part for that. You however need to worry about exclusive file locking then.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this helps

```
 RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("/home/hduser/Documents/Sample.txt", "r");
        String line;
        long length = 0;//used to check the file length
        while (true) {
            if(in.length()<length){//new condition to reset position if file length is reduced 
                in.seek(0);
            }
            if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                length = in.length();
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You may not like the answer but try use shell istead of writing Java program. I am Java developer myself but if only I hear that there is something to do with logs I try tu use unix/linux shell. Writing Java code will take you 20 times more time, you will probably not find all edge cases and it will be hard to change anything because your program will be 200 lines of code instead of 5.

And your code. It is far from perfect, though your concern was that is not compiling. Here you have your class Sir that will compile and even work. Sort of:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Reader implements Runnable {
  private volatile boolean isReading;

  private final File file;

  public Reader(final File file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("bf4logreader.Reader.run: File has not been found. file = " + file);
    }
    isReading = true;
    while (isReading) {
      String line;
      try {
        line = reader.readLine();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("bf4logreader.Reader.run: Something went wrong when reading file. file = " + file);
      }
      if (line == null) {
        //No new lines
        long startSleepTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          if (isReading) {
            //Not supposed to be interrupted
            try {
              Thread.sleep(System.currentTimeMillis() - startSleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          else {
            try {
              //Needs to shutdown
              reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex1) {
              Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        //Process new lines
        System.out.println("Line: " + line);
      }
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    isReading = false;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Reader reader = new Reader(new File("res/integers.txt"));
    new Thread(reader).start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    reader.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to suggest sometimes else than Java, then please add that to the answer, even more so when you point out that you have used it yourself. Unfortunately this will run on a Windows Server ultimately though. Also your Java suggestion does not properly cover the case were the second InterruptedException occurs.